# Primary key not AUTO INCREMENT in the PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, auto-increment

I have table Category and I  have 3 columns `category_id, category_name,category_description`.
When I execute insert script without `category_id` parameter I have this error:

```
ERROR:  null value in column "category_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, T_601, Yojimbo).
SQL state: 23502
```

This is my select script:

```
INSERT INTO category ( category_name, category_description)
    VALUES ('T_601', 'Yojimbo');
```

This is the image of my table : 
[image: t]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the data type to `serial`, which is Postgres's way of spelling `auto_increment`.  If you have a not-`NULL` integer column with no default, then you will get an error when you attempt an insert.

If you assign a default, then the unique constraint (part of the `primary key`) will just create a duplicate key error on the second insert.

Comment: Do you have any example how change type to serial?

Comment: @SInsansun . . . I don't use drop down menus to create tables.  I would assume that `serial` and `bigserial` are datatype options.  If not, just use `create table`.

Answer (score 7):

Use the following to add a serial to the column category_id

```
CREATE SEQUENCE cateogry_id_seq;
ALTER TABLE category ALTER COLUMN category_id SET DEFAULT nextval('cateogry_id_seq');
```

Now the column will be auto incremented and you don't have to enter the `catgory_id` column in insert queries